# Is it possible to make a non-virtual create method

Tags: c++, c++11, rtti

```
#include <memory>

class Base
{
    std::shared_ptr<Base> create() const; // Returns a default constructed object
}
```

Suppose, that all the members derived to whatever degree from `Base` are copy constructible and default constructible. I want the

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> create() const;
```

Method to create object of the appropriate dynamic type, but I do not want to use boilerplate code.

Is it possible to make

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> create() const;
```

Statically bound, but inside find somehow the correct type and create the object using Default constructor? Possibly using C++11.

Comment: A template?  `template <typename T> std::shared_ptr<Base> create () const { return new T (); };   p = create<Dervied1> ();`.  Maybe you could provide an example of how this might be used?

Comment: In the big picture, I am trying to make a function that accepts a class name in the form of a string and returns a std::shared_ptr<Base> with the appropriate dynamic type. I would like to implement this usinga a static std::map<std::string, Base*> object

Comment: @Martin: For your use case, static binding is not an option.  You need either a virtual call or a function pointer.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: Just a matter of style, your function should return a `unique_ptr`, since it's not yet being shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `create()` functions should probably be static, as you don't have an instance yet. But without parameters you cannot do what you want... unless you use templates, of course:

```
class Base
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    static std::shared_ptr<Base> create() const
    {
        return std::shared<Base>(new T);
    }
};
```

Then use it this way:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> ptr(Base::create<Foo>());
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> ptr(Foo::create<Foo>());
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually I have an instance. I have a std::shared_ptr<Base> object which points to an object of possibly different dynamic type than Base. Using this pointer I would like to request a default constructed specimen of the appropriate dynamic type.

Comment: Although this answer is not exactly what I was looking for, I trust Ben Voigt, that this is impossible. I will do it as you say. It actually solves my problem.

Comment: @Martin: I would argue that this answer doesn't get you anywhere. If you know the type you want to create, then you can easily create the shared_ptr --why call a function? Even with the function you need to specify two types: the one before ::create and the template parameter. Ugh as it is not needed! I would think you want to also handle the general case when you DON'T know any types except for the abstract base class --and for such this answer is (respectively) of little use. For example, how do you invoke create() with an iterator to list<shared_ptr<Base>>?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you have a static and perhaps a non-static `create()` functions. There is a clever way to accomplish this.

1. Define a `SuperBase` class. It needs a virtual destructor and a pure virtual `create()` function. You'll use pointers/references to this class for normal late-binding OOP behaviours.
2. Define a `Base` class template that inherits from `SuperBase`. `Base`'s template parameter will be the type of the `Derived` class. `Base` will also have a traits class template with a static function called `create()`. This static `create()` function will create a default object with `new`. Using the trait's `create()` function, `Base` will define both a `static_create()` and the pure virtual `SuperBase::create()` functions.
3. Implement `Derived` by inheriting from `Base<Derived>`.

One this is done, if you know you are using a derived type, then you can write `Derived::create()` to statically create a new one. If not, then you can always use an instance's `create()` method. Polymorphism is not broken since `SuperBase` would have the polymorphic interface you need/want --`Base<D>` is simply a helper class that auto defines the `static_create()` and `create()` functions so you would not normally use `Base<D>` directly.

Sample code appears below:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class SuperBase
{
  public:
    virtual ~SuperBase() = default;
    virtual std::shared_ptr<SuperBase> create() const = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct Base_Traits
{
  static T* create()
  {
    return new T;
  }
};

template <typename Derived, typename Traits=Base_Traits<Derived>>
class Base : public SuperBase
{
  public:   
    // Define a static factory function...
    static std::shared_ptr<SuperBase> static_create()
    {
      return std::shared_ptr<SuperBase>{Traits::create()};
    }

    // Define pure virtual implementation...
    std::shared_ptr<SuperBase> create() const override
    {
      return static_create();
    }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
};

int main()
{
  auto newone = Derived::static_create();  // Type known @ compile time
  auto anotherone = newone->create();      // Late binding; type not known @ compile time
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your approach!